# JavaScript (JSONP) приложение: поисковая оптимизация

Tags: javascript, seo, jsonp

Допустим, есть некий HTTP сервис, который предоставляет JSONP API и мне хочется написать сайт (приложение, не суть важно) исключительно с помощью JavaScript, HTML и CSS.

Дабы придать вопросу более яркую картину, допустим, этот сервис предоставляет [CRUD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) функционал, соответственно, контент не статичен и сайт (приложение) во многом, с т.з. содержимого скорее будет напоминать информационный (мультимедийный etc.) портал, к тому же, схема "статья = страница" невозможна, по понятным причинам. Итак, вопрос: как на это отреагируют мейнстрим поисковики? Как я понимаю, ненормально, но интересует более конкретная информация. И, конечно же, главный вопрос: как с этим бороться? Без использования серверного ЯП, юзаеться строго  html, css, js.

И еще небольшой под-вопрос: как гугл реагирует на использование HTML5  [history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)?

Comment: [ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/95513/хэш-в-урл-е#answer-container-95528) частично касается вашей темы

Comment: @Spectre - я знаком с hashbang нотацией, меня интересует не теория, а, непосредственно практика. К тому-же в главном вопросе, к сожалению, мне интересен не только гугл, но и, как минимум, яша

Comment: Яша тоже дружит с hashbang, остался вопрос HTML5 History API

Про HTML5 History API и поисковики замечательно написано [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193858/pushstate-and-seo). Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, никак. Без серверной части полноценная индексация сегодня невозможна. Можно рендерить специальными приложениями или писать изоморфный JS. Hashbang всего-лишь указывает поисковику, что специальную версию страницы для него искать нужно по адресу _escaped_fragment_. Для HTML5 history API нужно добавлять мета тег `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`.

Comment: +1. Только никаких `<meta` добавлять для `pushState`, надо просто с сервера возвращать адекватные странички по всем URL'ам, которые вы pushState'ите - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6194427/1026